# Why is there a difference between SEC filing date and a Date of Event for an SC-13D form?

Tags: stock-markets, sec

AMC just [filled](http://investor.amctheatres.com/sec-filings) today, May 1st 2020, an [SC-13D](http://www.snl.com/Cache/IRCache/c9c5e68b3-fe5c-6591-b84e-bd29cca2b0f2.html) form that has the, "Date of Event which Requires Filing of this Statement" set as "July 23, 2019".

Why is there a difference between the reporting dates?

Answer (score 1):

Companies are required to file a Schedule 13D within 10 days after the purchase.
[SEC.gov: Schedule 13D](https://www.sec.gov/fast-answers/answerssched13htm.html)

It is not clear that that is the same as the "Date of Event which Requires Filing" is the same as the date of purchase, nor if there were other reasons why it did not need to be published within 10 days of July 23, 2019.

Comment: Is there a way to find out what triggered this filing?

Comment: You could contact the SEC and ask them. https://www.sec.gov/answers.shtml